# How does Django handle escaping when I use a TinyMCE editor?

Tags: python, html, css, django, templates

How do I display only bolds, italics, and all the other non-security issue HTML on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sanitizing HTML is a pretty hard problem to get right. Spammers and other nasty people come up with new ways to smuggle HTML through sanitation all the time. The safest option is to define a white list of harmless tags and rigorously filter out all other tags with a true HTML parser (**not** with regular expressions).

There are a couple of template tags and filters on djangosnippets.com, e.g. [this](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/205/) or [this one](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1655/). When selecting a filter, pay attention that it uses a white list and an HTML parser like [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) (preferably [lxml.html.clean](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#cleaning-up-html)) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html).

Answer (score 2):

Probably it makes more sense to configure TinyMCE that way the user can only enter elements you allow him. TinyMCE has [a powerful set of rules](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/valid_elements) for that. If you are using django-tinymce see [this](https://django-tinymce.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release-1.5/docs/.build/html/installation.html#id2) for setting `TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG` to your desired options.

Comment: A malicious person would only have to disable JavaScript (or use a tool that doesn't interpret JavaScript in the first place) to get around that hurdle. **Never** rely on client-side validation alone. TIMEX asked for security, and this doesn't provide any security at all.

Answer (score 1):

To display all HTML (no-escaping) you can use `safe` filter

```
{{ var|safe }}
```

In your case, if you want to escape everything except certain tags, you can write you own filter that does that:

```
{{ var|mysafe }}
```

Read about it here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

The algorithm of the filter could be:

1. Escape everything
2. Unescape only those tags that are
   allowed (by using `.replace` or
   regilar expressions)